# adjust menu bar and right side icons

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

designed using bootstrap, trying to adjust the menubar in left side and icons will be right side. But there was a huge space in between menubar and icons. I want to set menubar near to signup button.

code:-

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="ss" class="col-lg-9">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Services
                <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 3</a></li>
                </ul>   
             </li>
            <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"> Sign Up</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"> Login</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Expecting output :- 
[image: Expected website like this]

Actual output: - [image: output is displaying like this]

Comment: Where's the CSS? You must have added something for it to be inline. Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/15xkx10c/

Comment: I did not write css for inline block. automatically bootstrap is given output with inline.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is any specific HTML you need to adhere to, but the behaviour you want could be achieved by **nesting** various **bootstrap .rows and .col-'s**.

Example based on your expected output:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <h1>Logo</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 re-order">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="ss" class="col-lg-12 first">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Services
                        <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu 3</a></li>
                        </ul>   
                     </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 second">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"> Sign Up</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"> Login</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

If you want the navigation to appear before the sign up / login (but come first in the HTML), you can switch those two cols with the following media query:

**CSS:**

```
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .re-order .row{
        display: flex;
        display: -ms-flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      }
      .re-order .row .first {
        order: 2;
      }
      .re-order .row .second {
        order: 1;
      }
    }
```

If the order of the HTML doesn't matter you can just switch around the order of the **first** and **second** columns.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/15xkx10c/3/

This looks exactly like your "expected outcome" picture.
I added the classes `first` and `second` to your navigation bars and the following CSS:

```
.first {
  float:left;
}

.second {
  float:left;
  clear:both;
}
```